# Black screen after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: screen, amd-graphics, 18.10

After updating to 18.10 from 18.04, Ubuntu boots into a black screen without showing a login page. The Ubuntu splash screen displayed for several seconds  and then everything went black. Ctrl+Alt+F5 didn't do anything. When booting with `nomodeset` UI animations don't work properly and CPU rendering makes the system slower.

Log of the failed boot: https://hardbin.com/ipfs/QmPGBULpPkL3HunGFGMtM1AxXAdveC48MfoBm6R2VU3rY9/#JAjPCLZCYMAJ9jxUFGcwkDXnwHBHhBdH9preyWRE8Xhm
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmR61awkJCmieGesxGops4MfzmSvLx32rnRNE9E2L4UFpm

Log of the successful boot:
https://hardbin.com/ipfs/QmcPB1GjfNhu9pGcZCMqw9g11k8yXQytWpxpA2Np9fC88e/#3o71n7F67qp6RqRJxmCgSBRBLdKJJMX5N4yxLC17rPQF
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZ1z3RZkEX2FDzkiAbG9yVn73XpkkCzyULUxU84MTE3eh

Output of `lspci -xxxx -nn -vvv`:
https://hardbin.com/ipfs/Qmbf3PcmzYX4kugBiHT7bmChKh7a7iokxxnajfzjtr1MWN/#BQ53oAiyVPtinFviLnuiBMUuHZZo113zzrfojsqWF2xs
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmbgV82CxukKLx235t9BeQEsypd2QPd4WjQqJpTaog5YDx

Booting with `modprobe.blacklist=amdgpu,radeon`:
https://hardbin.com/ipfs/QmX8jPcA1wLaFyLwqKbiKEU3BNvRap3aKkdBQYA1wYwujz/#HJL5Rk1dkfv5iFPCB687mrbUhGEwct2whiB8usc6bzgk
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQjRU35H8XGu9uBerpaj6H7ai4pKtknfF1vzpT9oToJVR

Comment: The links are not working. Better to use [paste.ubuntu.com](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and use the link option.

Answer (score 0):

This graphics card Intel UHD Graphics 620, is on the official supported list. I would just boot with the nomodeset option if it works.